# How to incorporate the word "misc" in sentences

Tags: grammar

I understand that misc is abbreviation of miscellaneous.

When writing this word should I write dot at the end like this: "Please look at the misc. folder"?
Also, should I use capital letter like so: "Please look at the MISC folder"?

Another example would be: "Please look under Categories for MISC/misc."

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it the name of a folder?

Comment: Neither of them reads very naturally. They would both be improved by the insertion of _the_ before misc./MISC

Comment: Hi @nschneid , I will choose the folder's name depending on your advice, but this is also a category in a our website.
So another example would be: "Please look under Categories for MISC/misc.

Comment: @mdewey thanks, you are right :) and as for the way of writing the word it self?

Comment: With "the" it sounds natural. Either "misc." or "MISC" will be widely recognized as short for "miscellaneous".

Comment: I personally never put stops in abbreviations, I find it old-fashioned but I believe learners of English are taught to do it. If the actual name is MISC then write MISC but otherwise there seems no need. Your profile name is not EVRAKEDABRA for instance.

Comment: @nschneid Thank you! so is the any benefit to add the dot in the word, even when in the middle of the sentence? (I just find it mildly confusing as it is in the middle of the sentence

Can I also use:
MISC.
and simply misc without a dot

I'm looking if there is a preferred way.

Comment: @mdewey Can you explain what is "stops in abbreviations"?
Is the old-fashioned way is adding a dot or writing in capital letters, Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Adding punctuation. For instance I would abbreviate Doctor as Dr without a stop and United States of America as USA, not U.S.A. But as I say I may be unusual in this.

Comment: "Full stop" is a (mainly British) term for "period."

Comment: Thank you all for answering :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends if the *name* of the folder is literally "Misc" or if it just *an unnamed folder which contains miscellaneous items*.

If it is just a folder which contains miscellanea then you should describe it in words and write something like "Please look at the miscellaneous-items folder."

If it has a name you should refer to it using that specific name, set off somehow (like "quotes" or `codetext` if your word processor allows for that): "Please look at the `Misc` folder." Whether you use a period or not depends on the actual name of the folder.

Generally, you would not use the appreciated form of the word in a full sentence. You could use the abbreviation as a heading in a table, for example. In that context the period is truly optional in my opinion.

And as mdewey commented, you need a **the** before the noun.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
You wrote "abbreviation as a heading in a table", I will use it as a category name in our website's list of categories. In that case would you use MISC or misc?
I let go of the period as I understand it's optional.

Comment: The proper use would be `Misc`. You should use that and then you can apply [the CSS `text-transform` property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) as desired to match your organization's branding and style.